# Нужна помощь со стеком с++!

Tags: c++

Определить, сколько элементов стека, начиная с вершины, находится до элемента с максимальным значением. Не могу понять почему работает неправильно. Кто может помочь исправьте ошибки. Вот мой код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Stack

{

    int info;
    Stack *next;

}*begin1;


Stack* InStack(Stack*, int);

void View(Stack*);

void mima(Stack*);



int main()

{

    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 101; i++)

    {
        begin1 = InStack(begin1, rand() % 101 - 50);

    }

    View(begin1);

    mima(begin1);

    getchar();

}


Stack* InStack(Stack *p, int in){

    Stack *t = new Stack;

    t->info = in;

    t->next = p;

    return t;

}




void View(Stack *p)

{

    Stack *t = p;

    while (t != NULL)

    {
        cout << t->info << "\n";

        t = t->next;

    }

}

void mima(Stack *p)
{
    if (p) {
        int max = p->info;
        int cnt1 = 0, cnt2 = 0;

        p = p->next;

        while (p) {
            cnt1++;

            if (p->info > max) {
                max = p->info;
                cnt2 += cnt1;
                cnt1 = 0;
            }

            p = p->next;
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        std::cout << cnt2 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что в вашем понимании "вершина" стека? Его корневой элемент или последний добавленный? Если последний – то, кажется, всё работает, не считая того, что стек организован "наоборот" (указатель next указывает на предыдущий элемент стека)

Comment: В моем понимании вершина стека - это последний добавленный элемент. Дело в том, что оно выводит неправильно количество элементов